# Using YQL to query a website

Tags: jquery, json, select, drop-down-menu, yql

This is what i am trying to do:

1. When the user clicks the search button use YQL to query the Nobel Prize website.
2. Parse the resulting JSON and display the results of the laureates who won the prizes.
3. Clear out the results if the user changes the year.
4. Clear out the results if the user changes the category.

My dropdown is working but is not clearing the results; and my YQL is not showing any results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTCgJo4phso -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>YQL XKCD</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnGetCurrent").click(function () {
                path = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fxkcd.com%2Finfo.0.json%27&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";
                requestCrossDomain(path, function (results) {
                    resultObj = JSON.parse(results);
                    $("#imgNobel").attr("src", resultObj.img);
                    $("#numNobel").attr("max", resultObj.num);
                    $("#numNobel").val(resultObj.num);
                }); //end requestCrossDomain call
            }); // end btnGetCurrent click

            $("#btnGetNumber").click(function () {
                alert("HI");
                path = "http://xkcd.com/" + $("#numNobel").val() + "/info.0.json";
                alert(path);

                requestCrossDomain(path, function (results) {
                    resultObj = JSON.parse(results);
                    $("#imgNobel").attr("src", resultObj.img);
                }); //end requestCrossDomain call

            }); // end btnGetCurrent click

        });     //end document ready

        function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {
            if (!site) {
                alert("Not site was passed in");
                return false;
            }

            var yql = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=json'
            alert(yql);
            //final ?
            $.getJSON(yql, function (data) {
                alert(data.query.results.body);
                callback(data.query.results.body);
                /*
                for (var name in data.query.results.body) {
                alert(name);
                }
                */

            }); //end getJSON
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>YQL XKCD</h1>
    <input id="btnGetCurrent" type="button" value="GET CURRENT LAUREATES WINNERS" />


    <img id="imgNobel" src="" alt="" /><br />
    <input id="numNobel" type="number"
        min="1901"
        max="2014"
        step="1"
        value="1901" />
    <input id="btnGetNumber" type="button" value="GET NUMBER" />
    <select>
        <option value="physics">physics</option>
        <option value="medicine">medicine</option>
        <option value=" peace">peace</option>
        <option value="literature">literature</option>
        <option value="economics">economics</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably looking for "Cascading dropdowns."

Comment: I'll look into that, hopefully that works cause this is giving me a headache.